# Django Mezzanine CMS base urls.py location?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, mezzanine

I'm a Django newbie and looking at Mezzanine CMS and looked at all URLs, can somebody point where http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/ is defined, what urls.py, I'm guessing it is

```
urlpatterns = [
url("^(?P<slug>.*)%s$" % ("/" if settings.APPEND_SLASH else ""),
    views.page, name="page"),
]
```

is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Mezzanine page urls are not defined explicitly in a urls.py, but are stored in the database in the `Page` model's `slug` field. You can navigate to the "about" page and the admin and modify its slug field there.

Note that in practice, page views are always intercepted and returned by `mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware`, which could be relevant for debugging purposes.